# ffmpeg closes with return code 137

Tags: linux, unix, video, encoding, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to convert videos and about 66% of the times doesn't do it's job until the end. It simply gets killed, closes before it ends the job, and returns "137" instead of "0".

I can't seem to find anywhere some information about this return code. Does anyone know some tips or where can I find further guidance? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

137 (128 + 9) means it's been killed with signal 9 (`SIGKILL`). This usually means that *something* sent `ffmpeg` this signal, not that the program crashed on its own.

Could it be that there is some process watching for long-running `ffmpeg` and killing them?

Another possibility is that your `ffmpeg` process oversteps its `ulimit` quotas and it gets killed by the system (although I'm not sure if it would get killed with `SIGKILL` and not `SIGABRT` in that case). Run the command `ulimit -a` and check for suspiciously low quotas.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I will talk with my sys admin and check thinks out.

Comment: Came to this page with the same error. After more debugging, it turned out that ffmpeg was using up all the memory (+swap)…

Comment: Came to this page with the same error. After reading Dave's comment, it turned out that ffmpeg was using up all my memory as well…